# why I still got duplicate messages in kafka after I set enable.idempotence = true

Tags: apache-kafka, duplicates

I have a question on how to avoid sending duplicate messages to kafka server.  I noticed that I was able to send the same message again and again and they do appear on the message system.

I tried setting the  enable.idempotence to true and this was verified in the application log:

> 2023-02-25 17:47:58.111  INFO 23828 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: acks = 1 batch.size = 16384 bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092] connections.max.idle.ms = 540000 enable.idempotence = true

But I was still able to publish the same message to kafka and I do see the duplicate messag

> "Hello duplicatemessage" Offset: 15   Key: empty   Timestamp: 2023-02-25 18:03:12.367 Headers: TypeId: java.lang.String
>
> "Hello duplicatemessage" Offset: 16   Key: empty   Timestamp: 2023-02-25 18:03:16.239 Headers: TypeId: java.lang.String
>
> "Hello duplicatemessage" Offset: 17   Key: empty   Timestamp: 2023-02-25 18:03:42.966 Headers: TypeId: java.lang.String

I thought the duplicate messsage should not be published.

Is this right? If not how do we avoid the duplicate message?

Comment: What do you mean "publish the same message"? The offsets are distinct. Kafka does not compare the key and value every time you call send function to what's already been sent

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong.

Your application as a producer, can send the same message N number of times. It is duplicate, only for you. Not from kafka perspective.

Kafka idempotent producer - is particularly for kafka-client during retries, it will ensure that it does not add the same message twice.  That is , your application sent only once. but due to network issues, the kafka client retried few times - here kafka-client as an idempotent producer, will not add duplicate messages.